# Why can't i check the return of a function with a switch?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, return

With if statements it is possible to check the return of an integer function.
The function gets executed within this.

```
if(!yourfunction)
{
     do something;
}
else
{
     do something else;
}
```

The very same thing in switch however, won't even execute the function. Why?

```
switch(yourfunction())
{
      case 1:
            do something;
      case 0:
            something else;
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: It ***is*** possible. However, you appear to be using invalid syntax for your switch statement.

Comment: @vortexman100 Not my downvote, but your `switch` is missing braces, break's and a default. So it's kind of hard to guess what you are asking, and you didn't care to explain what exactly `doesn't work`.

Comment: Do you mean that in the `switch` statement, `yourfunction` is not even called? You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And tell us how you check if `yourfunction` is called or not. And are you sure it actually only returns `0` or `1`? It can't return some other non-zero value for "true"?

Comment: I guess it's downvoted because you describe the problem as "doesn't work" instead of explicitly describing *how* it doesn't work. That is, what behaviour are you seeing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your edit does not improve the question much. "won't even execute the function"...that is probably an incorrect conclusion. But we can't tell you for sure and why unless you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your support, missing breaks was the problem. Well, i still have much to learn

Comment: Besides learning how to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm really confused about what you're asking. This is most certainly possible. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Nothing in your question suggests that missing `break`s could be the problem. That would only affect what happens after the function is called. Given `switch(yourfunction()) ...`, the function would be called.

Comment: @KeithThompson The really mistifying part is `The function gets executed within this... if(!yourfunction) ...` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done - however your function should be returning an int.

```
int foo(void) { return 1; }

int main(void)
{
    switch(foo()) {
    case 0:  
            printf("foo\n");
            break;
    case 1:  
            printf("bar\n");
            break;
    default:
            break;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

As, can been seen this compiles and runs.

```
[09:36 PM] $ gcc -Wall -Werror switcht.c -o switcht
[09:36 PM] $ ./switcht 
bar
[09:36 PM] $
```

However, if your function returns anything other than int then it wont compile. For instance if `foo()` return `float`:

```
float foo(void) { return 1.0; }
```

Then:

```
[09:44 PM] $ gcc -Wall -Werror switcht.c 
switcht.c: In function ‘main’:
switcht.c:7:9: error: switch quantity not an integer
switch(foo()) {
     ^~~~~~
[09:44 PM] $
```

Comment: There wasn't a 3rd case in OP's question. The literal translation would rather be `case 0: /* do something */ break; default: /*do something else */ break;`.

Comment: The question lacks the declaration of the function. You show a (wrong) pattern and speculate about the rest.